# How can I reset all events after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load data via ajax pagination.

I set event for each data like this (Each data has a html class, named `like`)  :

```
$('.like').change(function() {
    alert(checked);
})
```

But every time `ajax` call, each data element getting more and more event. For example, if three `ajax` call happended and three chunk of data set were loaded, then  `alert()` occurs three times when one of first dataset elements would be `changed`l because above `js` code is called called three times...

Actually I use 3rd-party library. Here is a full code:

```
$.endlessPaginate({
    paginateOnScroll: true,
    paginateOnScrollMargin: 50,
    onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
        $('.like').change(function() {
            if (checked) {
                alert("hi");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `off` to unbind previous bindings:

```
onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
        $('.like').off('change');//APPEND THIS LINE
        $('.like').change(function() {
            if (checked) {
                alert("hi");
            }
        })
    }
```

**Or**
if you always use `.like`, instead of binding onComplete every time, you can use this code out of the ajax to act for all `.like` element:

```
$(document).on('change', '.like', function(){
    if (checked) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Both methods are correct and performance truly:

**Method1:**

```js
$(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){    
        $("#likes").append('<input type="text" class="like">');
        $('.like').off('change');//APPEND THIS LINE
        $('.like').change(function() {           
            alert("hi");
        });
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" >Add new like class</button>
<div id="likes">  
  <input type="text" class="like">
</div>
```

**Method 2:**

```js
    $(function(){
       
       $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#likes").append('<input type="text" class="like">');
        });
            
         $(document).on('change', '.like', function() {           
            alert("hi");
        });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="btn1" >Add new like class</button>
    <div id="likes">  
      <input type="text" class="like">
    </div>
```

Comment: First suggestion doesn't work... and If I use second one,   event doesn't set for  newly loaded data ... (or same effect as first one..)

Comment: @user3595632 Both way are correct. Review code snippet I've append

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation. That means you will set your event one time, outside of that plugin's code. Remove that event code from that plugin which sets it over and over, and just place the following code somewhere in your page:

```
$(document).on("change",".like",function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

This way you are getting the click event everywhere on the dom, and then if the clicked object has the `.like` class, the callback is executed. This will work for any `.like` element regardless if it existed on the dom originally, or added dynamically.

UPDATE: see working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pfu6d1gh/